# Mount SMB share (usb in router) on Raspberry error 56

Tags: pi-3, networking, mount

I'm having trouble mounting my USB in router on my Raspberry. Hope someone can help.

Status so far:

- I can access the drive on both my windows machine and mac machine.
- I can access the drive on my raspberry somehow (because it's shared?)[image]
- I've made a folder to mount it in: `/home/pi/mynas`
- After using this:

  ```
  $ sudo mount -t cifs //experia/main pi/mynas/ -o user=Lars,pass=pass.,dom=WORKGROUP
  ```

  I learned that I need to use the IP adress instead of the SMB name.
- After using this:

  ```
  $ sudo mount -t cifs //192.168.2.253/main /home/pi/mynas/ -o user=Lars,pass=pass.,dom=WORKGROUP
  ```

  I received this error message:

  ```
  $ mount error(112): Host is down
  ```

  I learned through Google that this is a bug of some sort and I need to add a version at the end of the command.
- My new command became:

  ```
  $ sudo mount -t cifs //192.168.2.253/main /home/pi/mynas/ -o vers=1.0,user=Lars,pass=pass.,dom=WORKGROUP
  ```
- This command results in `mount error(56): Invalid request code`. And this is where I get stuck. Searching for this error results hardly any results at all. I don't know where to turn anymore.[image]

Could it be that my router is simply not compatible with linux/raspberry? Searching for the error 56 only gave me one result, which was someone from my own country who also had issues, and looking at the name of his network drive he probably has the exact same router as me.